# Vuejs nested post and comment unwanted model binding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vuejs2

In my vuejs code, i am fetching data from a Rails Api, which works fine for the post, i can create a new post but when i want to post a comment and i type in one input field, it types on every other field, i'm a beginner, please help, i don't really know how to phrase a question. Here's the code

```
     <template>
       <div class="home">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-shadow">
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form class="form-group" @submit.prevent="postGossip" style="margin: 10px;">
              <textarea class="font-control" v-model="micropost.body" placeholder="What's Happening ?" style="padding: 10px;" rows="5"></textarea>
              <span style="color:red">{{ errors.body }}</span>
              <button class="btn btn-danger text-right pull-right">Post</button>
              </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-white post panel-shadow" v-for="post in microposts" transition="item">
            <div class="post-heading">
                <div class="pull-left image">
                    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" class="img-circle avatar" alt="user profile image">
                </div>
                <div class="pull-left meta">
                    <div class="title h5">
                        <b>Anonymous</b>
                    </div>
                    <h6 class="text-muted time">{{ getHumanDate(post.created_at) }}</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-description">
                <p>{{post.body}}</p>
                <div class="stats">
                  <div v-on:click="isShow = !isShow" class="text-right">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration: none;">Comments {{post.comments.length}}</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="post-footer" v-show="isShow">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment" type="text" v-model="comment.body">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="postComment">Post</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <ul class="comments-list" v-for="comment in post.comments">
                    <li class="comment">
                        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                            <img class="avatar" src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" alt="avatar">
                        </a>
                        <div class="comment-body">
                            <div class="comment-heading">
                                <h5 class="time">{{ getHumanDate(comment.created_at) }}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <p>{{comment.body}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>

    import moment from 'moment'
    export default {

      name: 'home',
      data () {
        return {
          micropost: {
            body: ''
          },
          errors: {},
          microposts: [],
          comment: {
            micropost_id: '',
            body: ''
          },
          isShow: false
        }
      },
      methods: {
        postGossip: function () {
          let self = this
          this.axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/microposts', {
            micropost: self.micropost
          }).then(function (response) {
            self.errors = {}
            self.microposts.unshift(response.data)
            self.micropost.body = ''
          }).catch(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
            self.errors = 'response.data.error'
          })
        },
        getPosts: function () {
          let self = this
          this.axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/microposts').then(function (response) {
            self.microposts = response.data
          }).catch(function (errors) {
            console.log(errors)
          })
        },
        postComment: function () {
          console.log(self.comment)
        },
        getHumanDate: function (date) {
          // return moment(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD/MM/YYYY')
          return moment(date).fromNow()
        }
      },
      mounted () {
        this.getPosts()
      }
    }

    </script>

    <style>
      body{
        background-image: url('../assets/background.png');
      }

      .panel-shadow {
          box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 3px 3px 3px;
      }
      .panel-white {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      }
      .panel-white  .panel-heading {
        color: #333;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #ddd;
      }
      .panel-white  .panel-footer {
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: #ddd;
      }

      .input-group-addon{
          background-color: transparent !important;
      }

      .post .post-heading {
        height: 95px;
        padding: 20px 15px;
      }
      .post .post-heading .avatar {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        display: block;
        margin-right: 15px;
      }
      .post .post-heading .meta .title {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      .post .post-heading .meta .title a {
        color: black;
      }
      .post .post-heading .meta .title a:hover {
        color: #aaaaaa;
      }
      .post .post-heading .meta .time {
        margin-top: 8px;
        color: #999;
      }
      .post .post-image .image {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      .post .post-description {
        margin: 15px;
      }
      .post .post-description .stats {
        margin-top: 20px;
      }
      .post .post-description .stats .stat-item {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 15px;
      }
      .post .post-description .stats .stat-item .icon {
        margin-right: 8px;
      }
      .post .post-footer {
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list {
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 20px;
        list-style-type: none;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 20px 0;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .avatar {
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-heading {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-heading .user {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: 10px;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-heading .time {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #aaa;
        margin-top: 0;
        display: inline;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment .comment-body {
        margin-left: 50px;
      }
      .post .post-footer .comments-list .comment > .comments-list {
        margin-left: 50px;
      }

      .item {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color: #eee;
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      }
      .item-enter {
        opacity: 0; /* the state right after enter (enter from this state) */
      }
      .item-leave {
        opacity: 0; /* the state right before leave (leave to this state) */
      }
      .item-enter-active, .item-leave-active {
        transition: opacity .5s ease; /* applied during enter/leave transition */
      }
      .item-move {
        border-color: red;
        transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.55,0,.1,1); /* applied during moving transition */
      }
    </style>
```

And this is what happens:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmSDx.png)

It writes on every comment box insert of just one, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the object `post`, that you get from the API returns many `comments`. Than in your iterator `v-for=comment in post.comments` you call the iteratee defined in your object locally as `comment`, what causes a "collision" with the object your defined in your component `data`.
As `post` is also a iteratee of microposts you should add the newly created object to microposts. Try the following.

change the iteratee name v-for='comment in post.comments' to `c`. Of course change the references also in

```
<div class="comment-body">
  <div class="comment-heading">
    <h5 class="time">{{ getHumanDate(c.created_at) }}</h5>
  </div>
  <p>{{c.body}}</p>
</div>
```

Then your postComment method you can clone the object | [clone an object](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/971)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="postComment(post)">Post</button>
```

Define the method

```
postComment: function (post) {
  post.comments.push({body: this.comment.body});
}
```

Remember that if a comment has other fields, you need to set them before appending to the parent object `post`

Comment: Apparently, this didn't solve my problem it's still binding it, but i'm grateful for your answer nevertheless

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.comment)) should create a clone object (didnt test it tough). But you could try a _.clone(this.comment) using lodash.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase my comment,  it did actually work, i'm referring to the tying stuff where i'm commenting on one post and same comment is typing everywhere, how do i stop that

Comment: Right, I just edited it the answer. Take a look. You will get the idea. This should solve your problem